# when to use @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) and @SpringBootTest it test classes

Tags: spring, testing, junit, annotations

i currently wonder what is the real difference between
this snippet of code

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class TestClass1 {
    
    // some code

}
```

ant this one..

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TestClass2 {
    
    // some code

}
```

what can we do in the first code that can't do in the 2nd snippet ?
and vice-versa :
what can we do in the 2nd code that can't do in the 1rst snippet ?

for me, in both cases, we can :

- use spring context
- work with junit

so.. what is the difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that you need to know

`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

1. Use to run integration tests and load Spring TestContext
2. JUnit annotations are also available to use
3. Not a rich API with respect to configuration

`@SpringBootTest`

4. Use to run integration tests and load Spring TestContext
5. JUnit annotations are also available to use
6. Offer a rich API to configure test configuration
7. Recommended as it supports new features and is simple to use